# htaccess mobile redirect issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I redirect mobile users to /mobile/ directory?

This code work for me only if users start navigate from main path (http://www.mywebsite.it) but if they click on a link on facebook (http://www.mywebsite.it/news/title-news/123.html) they reach the non-mobile version...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} blablabla [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mywebsite.it/mobile [R=302,L]
```

If I change the second line width this one:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.it/mobile [R=302,L]
```

the redirection is ok but the mobile version of website is inaccessible (images not displaying, jquery mobile doesn't work...)

Who can help me?

----|----

And if I want to exclude a subfolder? My back-end is responsive but now it is impossible to access at http://www.mywebsite.it/admin because .htaccess redirect to mobile version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to exclude your existent files  from the rule :

```
#--exclude existent files--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} blablabla [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.it/mobile/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Otherwise the Rule redirects them to the mobile directory.